# I got error like this when coding python with scapy module IndexError: Layer [<function raw at 0x7fb291839dc0>] not found

Tags: python, scapy

So i already fix the error that i need to use haslayer not hashlayer in my packet_sniffer program :

```
#!usr/bin/env python
import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers import http


def sniff(interface):
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packet)


def get_url(packet):
    return packet[http.HTTPRequest].Host + packet[http.HTTPRequest].Path


def get_login_info(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw):
        load = packet[scapy.raw].load
        keywords = ["username", "user", "login", "password", "pass"]
        for keywords in keywords:
            if keywords in load:
                return load


def process_sniffed_packet(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
        url = get_url(packet)
        print("[+] HTTP Request >> " + str(url))

        login_info = get_login_info(packet)
        if login_info:
            print("\n\n[+] Possible username/password >" + login_info + "\n\n")


sniff("eth0")
```

When i run this, it look completely fine until i got error like these after a couple of minute:

```
[+] HTTP Request >> b'fdrtire.com/assets/frontend/js/global.js'
[+] HTTP Request >> b'ocsp.pki.goog/gts1c3'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/packet_sniffer/packet_sniffer.py", line 33, in <module>
    sniff("eth0")
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/packet_sniffer/packet_sniffer.py", line 7, in sniff
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packet)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 1036, in sniff
    sniffer._run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 989, in _run
    session.on_packet_received(p)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scapy/sessions.py", line 82, in on_packet_received
    result = self.prn(pkt)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/packet_sniffer/packet_sniffer.py", line 28, in process_sniffed_packet
    login_info = get_login_info(packet)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/packet_sniffer/packet_sniffer.py", line 16, in get_login_info
    load = packet[scapy.raw].load
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 1185, in __getitem__
    raise IndexError("Layer [%s] not found" % lname)
IndexError: Layer [<function raw at 0x7fb291839dc0>] not found
```

what cause of these??

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what are the results?
Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Comment: okay wait let me edit it first